Reduction in apparent size as object moves from center to the boundary in the hyperbolic plane
This is probably a trivial question, but I can't find a straightforward answer. I'm reading Penrose's book "The Emperor's New Mind", and when he refers to hyperbolic geometry, he offers a drawing by Escher as illustration of the concept. In the drawing Escher paints black and white fish inside a circle of hyperbolic geometry. Fish that lie on the center are drawn the largest and fish far away and closer to the boundary are drawn smaller and smaller.
I learned that, in hyperbolic geometry, the area is invariant so if I were part of the drawing, I'd find all the fish being of the same size. However when I am outside their circle, in a Euclidean world, I see the fish having their size proportional to how close they are to the center of the circle. I read that apparent size decays exponentially because "the surface of spheres grows exponentially with radius" (section "What changes in Hyperbolic Space?"), but I can't find an exact equation.
I'd like to know what is the equation for the rate of change in the apparent size of shape as an object moves from the center to the boundary of the hyperbolic plane.

The "Lines and distances" section of Wikipedia's "Poincare disk model" entry gives relations to translate between "apparent" distance in the Euclidean model and "actual" distance in the hyperbolic plane. In particular, a segment of Euclidean length $r$ with an endpoint at the center of the disk has hyperbolic length $\ln\dfrac{1+r}{1-r}=2\operatorname{arctanh} r$.  (Note that as $r$ approaches $1$, this value approaches infinity.) Non-"radial" distances are trickier.

Thank you Blue. Not sure if I follow the article well. I take a blank page and draw a circle of radius 1cm. What lies inside the circle is hyperbolic. Outside of it I draw a straight line 0.1cm long. Now I want to draw the same line inside the circle (with one of its ends at the center). I'm about to draw a line 0.2cm long ($2arctanh(0.1=0.2$). Then I draw a 2nd line outside, 0.9cm long, and in similar spirit I need to draw a line of 2.9cm ($2arctanh(0.9)=2.9$). But my circle is only 2cm in diameter. Unlike Escher's fish, my shape seems to have gotten bigger not smaller. What am I mixing up?

To draw a Euclidean segment in the model (with endpt at the center) representing a hyperbolic segment of length $d$, the segment you draw has Euclidean length $r=\tanh(d/2)$. For $d=0.1$ and $d=0.2$, these values are $r=0.049\ldots$ and $r=0.099\ldots$. ... It may help to consider the "number line" of pts at hyperbolic distances $1,2,3,\ldots,10$ from the origin; this is modeled by pts at Euclidean distances $0.462$, $0.761$, $0.905$, $0.964$, $0.986$, $0.995$, $0.998$, $0.9993$, $0.9997$, $0.9999$. Clearly, the model pts quickly start bunching-up near the border of the model circle.

I see now! I had to think about it in the inverse, as if I were inside the circle looking up at its "sky" and projecting my number line at the dome. Your tip with the "number line" really helped. Thank you very much!
Do you know if from this I can move on to ratios of areas of circles, which I read are defined as $4\pi sinh^{2}{\frac{r}{2}}$, and after replacing $r$ with $tanh(d/2)$, and taking the fraction of two $d$s would give the fraction that I originally wanted?

Your "dome" visualization anticipates the "hyperboloid model" of the hyperbolic plane. Congrats on the insight! :) ... As for "the fraction that [you] originally wanted": In "Circle Limit I", the number line captures how the lengths of the "radial" fish shrink. Assuming hyp-length $1$, the $n$-th fish from the center has apparent length $f_n:=\tanh(n/2)-\tanh((n-1)/2)$ in the model; so, $f_m/f_n$ gives a "shrink factor". As the fish aren't similar in the model, areas aren't proportional, but $(f_m/f_n)^2$ may be a reasonable approximation.

It sounds like what you are really asking for is a detailed analytic description of the hyperbolic plane, in which case I suggest reading a textbook on the topic.

Thank you Blue! This makes a lot of sense to me. I can also see a link between your solution and the Wikipedia article about the distance of two points lying on the same radius. Your help has been immense. Thank you again so very much. If you want to compile an answer out of your comments, I'm happy to accept it. Concluding–If you, or Lee, have a intro textbook on hyperbolic geo to suggest, I'd love to hear it. Thank you again!
